# Mybatis How to map a column from another table to a String list?

Tags: java, string, collections, mapping, mybatis

I have a table t_comment, and a table t_comment_photo.

t_comment has column id, content;
t_comment_photo has column id, comment_id, photo_url.
t_comment_pohto contains the url of comment photos, a comment can have 0 to many comment photos.

These are their java classes:

```
public class ToyComment {
    private Integer id;
    private String content;
    private List<String> urls;
    ...
}
public class CommentPhoto {
    private Integer id;
    private String commentId;
    private String comment_url;
    ...
}
```

Here is the `<select>` content in mapper:

```
<select id="getToyCommentList"
    resultType="com.domain.ToyComment">
    c.id, c.content,p.user_photo_url userPhoto
    from t_comment c left join t_comment_photo p
    on c.id = p.comment_id
</select>
```

When I try to map the userPhoto queried from table t_comment_photo to a element of the list inside the java class ToyComment, I am getting errors.

The resultMap I am trying to fix is:

```
<resultMap id="ToyCommentResultMap" type="com.domain.ToyComment">
        <result column="id" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="id" />
        <result column="content" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="content" />
        <!-- <result property="urls"  jdbcType="VARCHAR" javaType="java.util.ArrayList" column="userPhoto" /> -->
        <collection property="urls" javaType="list" jdbcType="VARCHAR"  column="userPhoto"></collection>
    </resultMap>
```

I tried both `<property>` and `<collection>`, but neither are working.

When I used `<collection>`, I got "Mapped Statements collection already contains value for com.toy.mapper.ToyCommentMapper.getToyCommentListByToyId" error, when I used `<result>`, I got "No typehandler found for property userPhotos".
Use "java.util.ArrayList" or "list" for javaType doesn't change the output error.

I tried to search for "mybatis map to string list", but most are about mapping to a list of objects.

How to fix it right?

Comment: You can try this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8451425/10915910). Use foreach maybe help you.

Answer (score 2):

The result map should look as follows:

```xml
<resultMap id="ToyCommentResultMap" type="com.domain.ToyComment">
  <id column="id" property="id" />
  <result column="content" property="content" />
  <collection property="urls" javaType="list"
    ofType="string">
    <result column="userPhoto" />
  </collection>
</resultMap>
```

A few notes:

- Specify `<id />` when using `<collection />`. It improves efficiency and is required in some cases.
- In `<select />`, you need to specify `resultMap` instead of `resultType` (obviously).
- This is a tricky case and we have added an [FAQ entry](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-map-a-list-of-simple-type-objects-string-integer-etc-to-a-bean-or-map-) just recently.